# Colors In Text Editor Incorrect After Visual Studio 2017 Update 26430.04

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After updating to Visual Studio 26430.04 the color of my text is dark as if my theme is set to Light or Blue but my background is still Black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the theme to Blue and then back to Black.